# When executing linux rm command to delete a file is open, how to recover disk space?

Tags: linux

When executing linux rm command to delete a file is open, then poweroff and restart the machine, how to recover disk space?

Comment: In the embedded linux, I use ext4 file system,du -xsh result is 831.2M,but df -h used is 9.1G,so lost.

Comment: Small or large files?  ext4 "tiny" files uses only directory space

Comment: Please also provide the output of `mount` (or `/proc/mtab`) and `df -h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is automatic.  Just the opened file remains in the disk until they are closed (and a reboot will force closing programs, so the system closes that files).

a `fschk` will free the disk space if system was suddenly stopped (loss of electricity).  Note: file systems with journals and other will do this automatically.

Comment: In the embedded linux, I use ext4 file system,if I poweroff and restart,it can't free disk space.

Comment: do you mean "poweroff "as command (so a clean poweroff) or just powering off the device?

Comment: fsck.ext4 /dev/mmcxx can resolve problem.

Answer (score 0):

On a running system, you need to close the process that locks the file. It will mark as free the space used by the file that is being deleted.

You can find the PID of the process which locks your deleted files with this command : `lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'`

Once you get the PID list, you can try to close the corresponding program or to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply overwrite the deleted file data with an empty content.

Step 1: identify the process holding the disk space

Here PID 7995

Step 2: identify file descriptor pointing to the deleted file, here fd #13

```
$ lsof -p 7995 | grep deleted
ksh     7995 jlliagre   13w   REG  252,0    353831  72794942 /tmp/foo1 (deleted)
```

Step 3: redirect a null command to it

```
$ : > /proc/7995/fd/13
```

Step 4: verify the space is recovered:

```
 $ lsof -p 7995 | grep deleted
ksh     7995 jlliagre   13w   REG  252,0         0  72794942 /tmp/foo1 (deleted)
```